# C# LINQ append an item to the end of an array

Tags: c#, linq

I have an int[] array. I need to take an int and append it to the end of the array without affecting the position of the other items in that array. Using C# 4 and LINQ what is the most elegant way to achieve this?

My Code:

```
 int[] items = activeList.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
 int itemToAdd = ddlDisabledTypes.SelectedValue.ToInt(0);

 // Need final list as a string
 string finalList = X
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why don't you simply do a `finalList = activeList.Append("," + ddlDisabledTypes.SelectedValue)` ?

Comment: items.Add(itemToAdd); Does not work: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What @Steve is saying is, why convert the string to an array at all when the input is a string and the output is a string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to change your expression around a bit.  First convert to a `List<int>`, then add the element and then convert to an array.

```
List<int> items = activeList.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList();
int itemToAdd = ddlDisabledTypes.SelectedValue.ToInt(0);
items.Add(itemToAdd);

// If you want to see it as an actual array you can still use ToArray
int[] itemsAsArray = items.ToArray();
```

Based on your last line though it seems like you want to get all of the information back as a `string` value.  If so then you can do the following

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in items) {
  if (builder.Length != 0) {
    builder.Append(",");
  }
  builder.Append(item);
}
string finalList = builder.ToString();
```

If the overall goal though is to just append one more item to the end of a string then it's much more efficient to do that directly instead of converting to an `int` collection and then back to a string.

```
int itemToAdd = ddlDisabledTypes.SelectedValue.ToInt(0);
string finalList = String.IsNullOrEmpty(activeList)
  ? itemToAdd.ToString()
  : String.Format("{0},{1}", activeList, itemToAdd);
```

Comment: The last item is the best example. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 23):

Try `items.Concat(new[] { itemToAdd });`.

Answer (score 3):

Your example code seems really convoluted to match the conditions

using your code

```
List<int> items = activeList.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList();  
items.Add(ddlDisabledTypes.SelectedValue.ToInt(0));  

string finalList = String.Join(',',items.ToArray());
```

Just manipulating the string

```
int itemToAdd = ddlDisabledTypes.SelectedValue.ToInt(0);  
string finalList = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activeList) ? 
                                           itemToAdd.ToString() :
                                           itemToAdd + string.format(",{0}",itemToAdd);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the item as `string` directly?

```
string finalList = items + "," + itemToAdd;
```

`int` is automatically converted to `string` in concatenations.

if `items` can be `null` or empty then change the expression to

```
string finalList = String.IsNullOrEmpty(items) ? 
                     itemToAdd.ToString() : items + "," + itemToAdd;
```

Comment: what happens if items is empty?

Comment: I do not know the details of the OP's logic. Of cause he would have to check this case, if items can be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
 List<int> items = activeList.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList();
 int itemToAdd = ddlDisabledTypes.SelectedValue.ToInt(0);
 items.Add(itemToAdd);
```

**EDIT:**

And next if you want to have an array of int:

```
int[] array = items.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you use a String converted into an Array converted into a String..?
Could this be what you need?

```
string finalList = activeList + "," + ddlDisabledTypes.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use 'union' to create a new array, in this case the new element is at beginning:

```
class HelperX {
    /// <summary>
    /// Tenemos varios campos tipo bandera, cuyo valor puede ser 'S' = Sí o 'N' = No
    /// </summary>
    static public KeyValuePair<string, string>[] SiNo
    {
        get
        {
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "S", "Sí"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "N", "No")
            };
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tenemos varios campos tipo bandera, cuyo valor puede ser 'T' = 'Todos', 'S' = Sí o 'N' = No
    /// </summary>
    static public KeyValuePair<string, string>[] SiNoTodos
    {
        get
        {
            var todos = new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "T", "Todos"),
            }.Union(SiNo);

            return todos.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, I can create a selectListItem to display them as select option in the View:

```
ViewBag.SeleccionSiNoTodos = HelperX.SiNoTodos
  .Select(kv => new SelectListItem() { 
          Value = kv.Key, 
          Text = kv.Value, 
          Selected = seleccionados?.Contains(kv.Key) == true })
  .ToList();
```

Finally, within a view I can get a Select option list by using:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SeleccionSiNoTodos", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SeleccionSiNoTodos)
```